# Quarkus resteasy-reactive upload byte[] without file creation

Tags: java, quarkus, quarkus-reactive

I want to keep uploaded files only in memory, so I tried to create a service that accepts multipartformdata as byte[]. However, every upload creates a temporary file and I cannot let this run stateless / read-only.

I use it like this

```
public class FormData {
    @FormParam("myFile")
    @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public byte[] binaryPart;
}
```

Comment: It might be because the default max body size is 1MB, and perhaps that is why it is using files.   In my opinion, I think if  you use MultiPart it should create files, so that it knows where it left off incase of disconnection (How to resume), but you could play with the `quarkus.http.limits.max-body-size` and see if that helps you.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61949759/how-to-handle-large-file-uploads-in-quarkus

Comment: What does the entire JAX-RS resource look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this with Quarkus Version 3+ by using a JAXB-Class like this:

```java
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MultipartBody {

    @RestForm("name")
    @XmlMimeType((MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN))
    String name;

    @RestForm("file")
    @XmlMimeType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    byte[] bytes;
}
```

I think this was simply a bug in the resteasy-reactive implementation that has been fixed in later Quarkus versions. In Quarkus 2 I had  to rely on resteasy-classic.